# What is the meaning of <type> tag within <dependency> tag?

Tags: java, maven, build, dependency-management

The same dependency is declared with no `<type>` and with `<type>test-jar</test>` in two different projects I am working on. However, I didn't manage to find a proper explanation of what it means.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally, test classes are not packaged into the jar; they're executed during the build and then only the main classes are exported.

However, there are some cases where you do want to export the test classes for some reason, and you can package them into a `test-jar`. An example of when you would do this is when you have integration tests (such as REST or Selenium) that require your application to be packaged up and deployed into a staging environment. Your CI server can deploy the `jar` and then get the `test-jar` and run the test classes from it.

Comment: So, when my project declares a dependency on an artifact with type `test-jar` it means that it is not dependant on the main classes, but on the test classes of the artifact as well?

Comment: @akaRoga Correct. Perhaps, for example, there's an abstract base class for Selenium tests or something that it uses.

Comment: It is also nicely explained here https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.6.1/maven-model/maven.html#dependency, and has a link to where mapping provided by Default Artifact Handler (`dependency type <-> artifact definition`) is described https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.6.1/maven-core/artifact-handlers.html